# States of togglebuttons

Tags: android, state, togglebutton

Currently i am working on two toggle_buttons both are working perfectly, both are on different pages, saving their states, but i am having an issue, when i click the toggle_button_1 on page_1, it automatically set on the toggle_button_2 on  page_2, what i want to do is, when i click the toggle_button_1 on page_1, it disable the toggle_button_2 on page_2, until and unless i make the toggle_button_1 set off, toggle_button_2 remain disable. i am using this code for both toggle_buttons on different pages.

Can anyone help me in doing my task???

```
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    s2.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton", false));


    s2.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", s2.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
```

Comment: make sure you are using different keys for the boolean value saved in your sharedpreference for both togglebutton.

Comment: I am using different keys for both of them, but both set on, when click one them.

Comment: any other suggestion which you wanna give regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by different "pages" -- do you mean [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), or something else?

In either case, I'd guess some sort of ID or key is the same, from your description -- perhaps even something in the [xml layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

If they are different Activities, then perhaps there's a race condition or something to do with the application lifecycle that's causing the data to be going bad; but double and triple check all the variables, ids and keys before going too far down the theoretical path.

If you provide more information, someone may be able to answer more effectively.  Key pieces of information may include any async tasks or details about how the activities are started, as well as clarifying the rest of the app's structure and lifecycle.

Comment: Yes these are activities

Comment: Actually i am having 1 tooglebutton in one activity and 2nd in other activity, i pu all the ids and keys different for all the stuff... but not getting, why one i press one of them, i check on another one

Comment: To me it really sounds like a mixed up constant, variable or string... Check them all again and use a search in your IDE to be sure...

Comment: If you format your question better and add more info, you may attract more attention (and up-votes!).  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey did that work for you then?  If so, updating your answer with your solution may attract an upvote or two...  Consider up-voting answer as well if it was helpful ;-)

Comment: can you check this for me, i will send you my code, so you better get understanding of my problem please!